# xpages xp:fileDownload allowDelete="false", but user can delete attachments

Tags: java, xpages

i have a simple filedownload control, in which I has to forbid deleting of the attachment(s). The option has no effect, the user see the icon (garbage ton) and cann successfully delete the attachment.

A bug? Do I misunderstood sth.?

thx, Uwe

```
<xp:fileDownload rows="30" id="fileDownload2" hideWhen="true" value="#{fback.SolutionAtt}" allowDelete="false" displayLastModified="true" displayCreated="false"></xp:fileDownload>
```

Comment: I have tested your code on `domino server 8.5.3 FP6` and I can't reproduce your problem. Which domino server do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't confirm this either. On my test system (Domino 9.0.1 FP4) the file download control behaves just as expected. I've set its properties to exactly the same values as in your code snippet (except the "value" prop of course, but that's irrelevant here). Setting `allowDelete="false`" means that the resulting table's "deletion" column is not rendered at all, so any specifics in Browser and/or css code shouldn't have any influence here.

Please check whether you have the entire Xpages code built into the final Java runtime class. Perform a Project >> clean and see what happens. Also look for compile time errors in your application that might stop code changes being compiled into the java classes. You could also try to make changes like static text alterations somewhere on the same page (or custom control, wherever your `xp:fileDownload` is located at), save it, then check whether those changes made it into your browser. If NOT then you'll have to look for compiler problems, otherwise there's a real mystery at work.

You should tell us your Domino versions (Designer AND server) as well as Domino Designer's language setting; only last week when giving an Xpages Developer training at a customer's site I hade to learn about some really weird bugs in the German language version of Domino Designer, so you never know...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Lothar and Georg. 
It must have been a strange cashing effect, because even a "clean" did not change it. 
What helps in the end was a renaming of the page and a stop/start of the http task on that server.

It was very helpful to read in your answers that you could not confirm the effect, so I knew that it must be sth in my system or design. 

thx, Uwe